# Inconsistent results between Graphql playground and Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I've run into an issue where Apollo client and the GQL playground return different data with the exact same query. The schema looks something like this:

```
interface A {
  age: Int!
}

interface B implements A {
  age: Int!
  name: String!
}

type SomeType implements A & B { ... }

type Query {
  hello: A 
}
```

The server returns a concrete type `SomeType`, which implements both interface `A` and `B`.

The query:

```
{
  hello {
    age
    ... on B {
       name
    }
  }
}
```

(The only difference I can think of is that when using Apollo client, the query is parsed with the `graphl-tag`).
In the GQL playground, the query returns the expect result. Something like:

```
{
  "__typename": "someType",
  "age": 10,
  "name": "someName"
}
```

However, when running this query with Apollo client, I get:

```
{
  "__typename": "someType",
  "age": 10,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the query is defined to return type `A`

```
type Query {
  hello: A 
}
```

So getting only the fields defined in `A` seems correct.
Perhaps you should change the schema to something like:

```
type Query {
  hello: SomeType 
}
```